# ZPL Code Get No of Copies #of10

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I'm looking to create a ZPL code to show the sequence of the labels being printed.
In this case i'm printing 10 copies of 1 label.

I want show on the right corner the number of the label
1/10 -- 1st copy
2/10 -- 2nd copy
etc.

Is this possible with ZPL?
I'm already using the ^PQ command to send quantity of copies.

Hope to hear from you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Serialization Field (`^SF`) command.

```
^XA
^FO250,40^A0N,70,70^FDLabel^FS
^FO150,240^A0N,50,50^FD001^SFddd^FS
^FO250,240^A0N,50,50^FDof^FS
^FO300,240^A0N,50,50^FD100^FS
^PQ100
^XZ
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was aware of this. Is there a possibility I can call the the PQ value as a variable? Because when my program start writing the ZPL string I don't know the quantity of prints.

Comment: If you are building ZPL on the fly with a program, prior to sending to the printer, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to change any character you wanted.